# Is Sourcetree the pull option the same as git pull?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Does Source tree default options for the pull dialog do the same as `git pull`?

I'm asking because it's not clear to me if the option "Commit merged changes immediately" add some special option to the command line.

[image]

Comment: [What exactly "Commit merged changes immediately" does?](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Git-questions/What-exactly-quot-Commit-merged-changes-immediately-quot-does/qaq-p/118289)

Comment: @Joe this option is scaring people away XD ...It shouldn't be called "pull" in the first place! Nobody wants to mess up a repository with some obscure option.